# Search MongoDB document for value in one or more fields

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

I have a search field in my application which I would like to query my collection in multiple ways. The search query which is input by the user needs to match either the `name` field or the `url` field. For example, a document that looks like this:

```
{ "name": "Google Maps", "url": "http://maps.google.co.uk/" }
```

Should be matched if I input `goog`, `//maps`, `maps google`, etc. – you get the picture. Just a case insensitive regex search on **multiple** fields.

I know how to use regex to search a field for a case insensitive value, but I'm new to MongoDB (and databases in general) and I'm not sure what the best solution would be for this. Do I need to implement a "compound index"? If so, how do I query against that index for the two fields?

Comment: What's the language/framework?

Comment: @joeframbach I'm using Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your input by spaces then add each to the list of queries to `$or`:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: {
    [
      {name: /goog/i},
      {url: /goog/i},
      {name: /\/\/maps/i},
      {url: /\/\/maps/i}
    ]
  }
})
```

In node:

```
var query = "maps google";
var ors = [];
query.split(" ").forEach(function(q) {
  ors[] = {name: new RegExp(q)};
  ors[] = {url: new RegExp(q)};
});
db.collection.find({$or: {ors} })
```

Comment: Depends on your version of mongodb.

Comment: I am doing this in production on a system of tens of thousands of paragraph-long descriptions. No problems at all

Comment: Mongo can only index on anchored regexes. That is, only searching for values that *start with* your query word